# Hide the "Failed to load" message when loading an invalid image, wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

```
bmp = wx.Image("C:\User\Desktop\cool.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
```

If i run this, it will automatically show an error message saying that it failed to load the image. How can I stop my program from doing this?

Comment: How can we convert this error this DialogBox into an `Exception` instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't even get my wxPython code to run if I pass it an an invalid image. This is probably related to the fact that wxPython is a light wrapper around a C++ library though. See http://wiki.wxpython.org/C%2B%2B%20%26%20Python%20Sandwich for an interesting explanation.

The best way around issues like this is to actually use Python's os module, like this:

```
if os.path.exists(path):
   # then create the widget
```

I do this sort of thing for config files and other things. If the file doesn't exist, I either create it myself or don't create the widget or I show a message so I know to fix it.

Comment: ah yeah, i guess theres no way

Comment: This works, but there could be some other errors : for example, the file exists, but the content is not a valid image. Then the popup would be displayed again.
Do you think it would be possible to restore this error handling as Exceptions ?

Comment: You might have to use sys.excepthook to catch this sort of thing

Answer (score 2):

If all you're after is to stop the exception from raising, you can enclose it in a try/except block:

```
try:
    bmp = wx.Image("C:\User\Desktop\cool.py", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
except:
    pass
```

Bear in mind, it's good practice to only ignore specific exceptions, and to do something when it occurs (ie tell user to pick another image):

```
try:
    bmp = wx.Image("C:\User\Desktop\cool.py", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
except <Specific Exception>, e:
    doSomething() # Handle exception
```

---

Since it's an actual pop up message, you can use `wx.Log_EnableLogging(False)` to disable error logging in your application

To stop stderr redirecting you can set `wx.App(redirect=False)`

Or to make error log to a file instead of onscreen you can use:

```
wx.App(redirect=True,filename='error_log')
```

Comment: The `try/except` doesn't work : this error is known handled as an `Exception`. But the `wx.Log_EnableLogging(False)` worked to stop the popup.

Answer (score 1):

For wxpython version 4+, I was able to disable the popup message by calling

```
wx.Log.EnableLogging(False)
```

or by calling

```
wx.Log.SetLogLevel(wx.LOG_Error)
```

Relevant docs [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/log_classes_overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `wx.Log_EnableLogging(False)` is `wx.LogNull`. From [the docs](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.LogNull.html):

```
# There will normally be a log message if a non-existent file is
# loaded into a wx.Bitmap.  It can be suppressed with wx.LogNull
noLog = wx.LogNull()
bmp = wx.Bitmap('bogus.png')
# when noLog is destroyed the old log sink is restored
del noLog
```